How to add keyboard shortcut for bar buttons
I have an iOS/iPad/Macos(Catalyst) app.
There is a toolbar configured as follows:
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(runSomeCode)),
    UIBarButtonItem(image: myImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveMyWork)),
    ...
]

I want to add keyboard shortcuts. For example Cmd+'a' to perform runSomeCode. And Cmd + 'I' to perform saveMyWork. The main target is Macos(catalyst) app.
How shall I assign these shortcuts to bar buttons?
